# 3D version of Chladni patterns

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a 3D pattern from this formula.

```
cos⁡(c1 x) + cos(c2 y) + cos(c3 z) = 0
```

where

```
0 < x < π, 0 < y < π, 0 < z < π
c1 = 1 ~ 8, c2 = 1 ~ 8, c3 = 1 ~ 8
```

Is there any way of coding this equation?

Comment: This website is not a coding service, I suggest you look up `ContourPlot3D` and `RegionPlot3D[]` in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You ask for 512 patterns. That is too many for anyone other than yourself to bother with. Particularly because the patterns get very complicated and slow to generate at high end of the range 1–8. However, here are two examples which can serve as a guide to your own work.

```
With[{c1 = 1, c2 = 2, c3 = 3},
  ContourPlot3D[
    Cos[c1 x] + Cos[c2 y] + Cos[c3 z], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, {z, 0, π}]]
```

[image: plot123]

```
With[{c1 = 3, c2 = 2, c3 = 8},
  ContourPlot3D[
    Cos[c1 x] + Cos[c2 y] + Cos[c3 z], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, {z, 0, π}]]
```

[image: plot328]